# Validation Failed when using accepts_nested_attributes_for with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, single-table-inheritance

First time I'm using STI, and I'm running into issues when trying to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with nested inherited objects.

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  # code removed for brevity
end

class DocumentItem < ApplicationRecord
   # code removed for brevity
end

class Package < Document
    belongs_to :user
    validates :title, :user, presence: true

    has_many :package_items, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :package_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class PackageItem < DocumentItem
    belongs_to :package
end
```

When I try and use nested attributes, things stop working:

```
Package.create!(title: 'test', 
                user: User.last, 
                package_items_attributes: [{title: 'test'}])
```

Which results in the following error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Package items package must exist`

I've tried setting `foreign_key` and `class_name` on the `belongs_to` relationship, with no luck:

```
class PackageItem < DocumentItem
    belongs_to :package, foreign_key: 'document_id', class_name: 'Document'
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

*UPDATE:*

This seems to be an issue with Rails 5 and associations having `required: true` by default. When turning off `required: true` and setting `foreign_key` on the `Invoice` model, it correctly assigns the parent model ID and saves the parent model and child models.

Comment: A thought: perhaps the associations should be declared on the parent classes instead? I.e. not PackageItem belongs to Package, but rather DocumentItem belongs to Document.

Comment: @henrebotha Pretty sure that would work. It would miss the point of using STI thought. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it has nothing to do with STI, and is a known Rails 5 bug. :(

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25198